# TextChanged event fires before bound text updates (Winforms .net6.0-winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-6.0

I want my price calculation to alter as I type, however the calculation is delayed.

My class is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyClass
{
    public class Model
    {
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal MarkUp { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal CalculatedPrice => Cost * (1 + MarkUp / 100);

    }


    public partial class FormTest : Form
    {
        public Model model { get; set; }
        public FormTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            model = new Model
            {
                Price = 0,
                MarkUp = 0
            };
            Calculate();
            bs.Add(model);
            textBoxCost.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Cost", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxMarkUp.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "MarkUp", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Price", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void textBoxCost_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }

        private void Calculate()
        {
            model.Price = model.CalculatedPrice; // does not have the most up to date value
        }
        private void textBoxMarkUp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate();
        }
    }
}
```

When I put a break in Calculate I see that the model has not updated.
What do I need to do?

[Update]

I now have the following:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _cost;
    public decimal Cost { 
        get => _cost; 
        set { 
        
            _cost = value;
            var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Cost));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,args );
        }  }

    private decimal _markup;
    public decimal MarkUp { 
        get => _markup;
        set { 
            _markup = value;
            var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MarkUp));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        } }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculatedPrice => Cost * (1 + MarkUp / 100);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

and

```
public partial class FormTest : Form
{
    public Model model { get; set; }

    public FormTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) { Calculate(); }

    private void AddBinding(TextBox textBox, string dataMember)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(propertyName: "Text", dataSource: bs, dataMember:dataMember);  
        
       // binding.Format += Binding_Format; // yet to do
        textBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }


    private void Calculate() { 
        
         model.Price = model.CalculatedPrice;
        }

    private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model = new Model { Cost = 0, Price = 0, MarkUp = 0 };
        model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;

        bs.Add(model);

        AddBinding(textBoxCost, "Cost");
        AddBinding(textBoxMarkUp, "MarkUp");
        AddBinding(textBoxPrice, "Price");
    }
}
```

It works when I press Tab to exit a field.
How can I make it work when KeyUp occurs?
The TextChanged event has the same issue.

I tried issuing bs.EndEdit from within the event code  but it did not help.

Comment: I think the model will only be updated after `bs.EndEdit()` or when you make another control focused

Comment: Your  Model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to propagate a Property Value change immediately.  -- Note that you can have formatting issues binding a `decimal` Property to Text.

Comment: I mean, you should handle the Binding's `Format` event and set, e.g., `e.Value` to `String.Empty` when its initial decimal value is `0`, otherwise it may be difficult to write numbers in the TextBox (since the Text is formatted automatically).

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
   private void textBoxCost_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        model.Cost = Convert.ToDecimal( tb.Text);
        Calculate();
         
    }

    private void textBoxMarkUp_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        model.MarkUp = Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text);
        Calculate();
    }
```